# mySQL order by has image AND id

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case, sql-null

I have a table with image column.
In that column - the values are the image URLs.
Now I want to get all the rows from the table in the following order:
first - the rows with images, ordered by id.
second - the rows without images, ordered by id.

I tried this code (I found it somewhere):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN image IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id DESC
```

but it doesn't work.

can you help me with it?

Thanks!

Comment: *but it doesn't work* - that's not useful. Lets see some sample data and desired results, ideally a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean expression:

```
image IS NULL
```

is evaluated as `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`, so you don't need a `CASE` expression.

Also, if for the 2nd level of sorting you want the rows *ordered by id*, I assume that you want them in ascending order, so you should not use the keyword `DESC`.

Change to:

```
ORDER BY image IS NULL, id
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. none of your code snippets. I still get only items without images, ordered by id.
The orderby id works fine. 
What I need is that first of all I'll get all the items WITH image, and then - the items WITHOUT.
Also - the image field isn't a boolean  field. It contains the image url. 
Maybe that is why it doesn't work? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AnneK what snippets? There is only 1: `ORDER BY image IS NULL, id`. If you have `null` in the column `image` then the rows with the `null` will be placed at the bottom of the results. This is what you asked for. If you get different results this means that either the data you have are different or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @AnneK I know that the column `image` is not boolean. The expression `image IS NULL` is boolean. Are you sure that you have `null`s in the column or maybe they are just empty/blank strings `''`?

Comment: It works! I changed to image = '' and now it works great. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

change  0 an 1:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN image IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, id DESC
```

or add DESC for the first order

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN image IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, id DESC
```

The default order is ASC and you must put the ORDER after each field. So
in your case you sort ASC for the image field and only DESC for the field id

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM orderby;
+-----+------+
| id1 | id2  |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    1 |
|   2 |    2 |
|   3 |    3 |
|   4 |    4 |
|   1 |    2 |
|   1 |    3 |
+-----+------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM orderby ORDER BY id1, id2 DESC;
+-----+------+
| id1 | id2  |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    3 |
|   1 |    2 |
|   1 |    1 |
|   2 |    2 |
|   3 |    3 |
|   4 |    4 |
+-----+------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM orderby ORDER BY id1 DESC, id2 DESC;
+-----+------+
| id1 | id2  |
+-----+------+
|   4 |    4 |
|   3 |    3 |
|   2 |    2 |
|   1 |    3 |
|   1 |    2 |
|   1 |    1 |
+-----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```